# how to parse html tags when writing to a excel file in PHP

Tags: php, excel

I have 2 questions

1) I want to fetch color code used inside span tag in the text

2) I want to parse html tags when writing to excel file to apply the color code used

example value from database as shown below

```
<p><strong> the test content goes here<span style="color: #800000;">It will be 
displayed</span> </strong></p>
```

i have the above text from a textarea is present in a variable so my requirement is to use any php excel library to write in a excel file so the formatting of text remains same like font color and bold

the approach i tried using spreadsheet_excel_writer as below

```
`$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$workbook->SetVersion(8);
$format_title =& $workbook->addFormat();
for ($j = 0; $j < count($all_values); $j++)
{
    for ($c = 0; $c < 24; $c++)
    {
        $format = $workbook->addFormat();
        $format->setColor('blue');

        if($c==7)
        $worksheet->write($i, $c,$all_values[$j][$c],$format);
        $worksheet->write($i, $c,$all_values[$j][$c]);
    }
    $i++;
}`
```

But this applies to the whole cell

I even tried to use PHPEXCEL but same in that too as it applies to the whole cell.

Here's [a link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.spreadsheet-excel-writer-format.setcolor.php) which i found to Set color in spreadsheet_excel_writer.

please help me with links and code solution is greatly appreciated

Comment: did you mean you like to apply color for font instead of cell's background?

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan: Nope i want to apply only font color not cell's background

Comment: have you tried the below solution

Comment: Thanks for your below solution , but in php excel it applies to the whole contents of the cell value A1 from your example . There may be case where some part of text in cell can have color and not renaming part

Answer (score 0):

Here I show simple example using phpExcel

```
//font configuration array
$fontConfig = array(
    'font' => array(
        'color' => array(
            'rgb' => '00FF00'
        ),
    ),
);

//PhpExcel Initialization
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$ActiveSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

//Color Applying
$ActiveSheet->SetCellValue('A1', 'Color Applied Here');
$ActiveSheet->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($fontConfig );

//Writing
$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel );
$writer->save('color.xlsx');
```

For Selecting color from tag use jQuery selector method.

```
$('p>strong>span').css('color');
```

And pass it in ajax or hidden value if you control this using form submission

Comment: $('p>strong>span').css('color'); to pick color i cant make use of jquery as iam not submitting the form , i actually fetch values from db and stored in array